# Child Entities not loaded when query joins tables

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a many-to-many relationship where Content has ContentTags which point to a Tag. I've put the relevant [Include] attributes on my entities to create the properties.

If I write enumerate `ObjectContext.Contents.Include("ContentTags.Tag")` then I get the ContentTags and Tags included as expected. When I use a join however the ContentTags are missing from my Content entity:

```
var contentsForTag =
    from c in ObjectContext.Contents.Include("ContentTags.Tag")
    join ct in ObjectContext.ContentTags on c.Id equals ct.ContentId
    join t in ObjectContext.Tags on ct.TagId equals t.Id
    where t.Name.ToLower().Contains(lowerTag)
    select c;
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening but I think it is because of a contradiction.
The join says that EF should load only the tags that containes lowerTag but the Include says that all tags should be loaded. I would guess EF can't resolve this and that is why none are included. You should be able to write your query without the join though

```
var contentsForTag =
    from c in ObjectContext.Contents.Include("ContentTags.Tag")
    where c.ContentTags.Any(ct => ct.Tag.Name.ToLower().Contains(lowerTag))
    select c;
```

Comment: Ah cheers, that's what I was looking for. Much nicer query format as well. Have to commit the Any extension method to memory for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var anonType =
    from c in ObjectContext.Contents
    join ct in ObjectContext.ContentTags on c.Id equals ct.ContentId
    join t in ObjectContext.Tags on ct.TagId equals t.Id
    where t.Name.ToLower().Contains(lowerTag)
    select new { Contents = c, ContentTags = ct, Tags = t }).AsEnumerable();

IList<Contents> contentsForTag = anonType.Select(c => c.Contents).ToList();
```

If you drop all relevant tables into an anonymous type EF will understand that you in fact need all of that info and will bring it back.  The best part is that EF will also take care of the auto-fixup, meaning all relationships will be maintained.  The last line of the sample simply extracts the desired objects from the anonymous type into a strongly typed list, however the rest of the graph is still alive and well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a "lazy-load" vs "eager-load" difference. The collection of Tags for a Content class is stored in a child table. Many ORMs including EF try to "lazy-load" collections and other many-to-one references, because it doesn't know if you'll need them and it would be a waste of bandwidth if you didn't. However, this means your tags aren't available in retrieved instances. To tell L2E that, yes, you really do need the tags, you specify that the child reference should be "eagerly" traversed when building the context.